How to store and use list of interface implementations in C#?
I would like to make a quick way of registering HangFire jobs. They all implement IJob interface (which contains Task Run()). Problem is I can't get the list to accept the models created that way. Example:
Example job:
public class CheckFilesJob() : IJob
{
    async Task Run()
    {
        // do something here
    }

Model I want to use on registration:
public class JobConfiguration<T>
    where T : IJob
{
    public JobConfiguration(string key, string queueName, Expression<Func<T, Task>> jobExpression, string cronExpression)
    {
        Key = key;
        QueueName = queueName;
        JobExpression = jobExpression;
        CronExpression = cronExpression;
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string QueueName { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<T, Task>> JobExpression { get; set; }

    public string CronExpression { get; set; }
}

How I want to instantiate the list:
new List<JobConfiguration<IJob>>
        {
            new JobConfiguration<CheckFilesJob>("Check Files",
                jobsConfiguration.Value.QueueName,
                x => x.Run(),
                jobsConfiguration.Value.CheckFilesSchedule),
            new JobConfiguration<AnotherJob>("Another Job", jobsConfiguration.Value.QueueName, x => x.Run(), jobsConfiguration.Value.AnotherJobSchedule)
        };

And how I want to use it:
    public static void HandleJobRegistration(
        this IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IEnumerable<JobConfiguration<IJob>> configurations)
    {
        // register each job here
    }

Problems:

I can't create a list of IJob, because implementation cannot be converted to interface (CS1503).
I can't seem to skip setting IJobConfiguration as generic, otherwise the jobExpression that is passed to the model belongs to the interface (not the implementation).
I can't use () => new CheckFilesJob().Run(), because it will look ugly with how many services need to be provided to the job.

Tried working with both generic and non-generic class, expecting to be able to somehow provide the proper expression. Tried different ways of providing the list as an argument to the function, to no avail.

What is the purpose of JobExpression ?

This is an XY Problem - the real problem X is how to automatically discover and register jobs in your project. You assumed you'd need explicit Job classes and registrations instead of expressions though, so now that this attempt at encapsulation failed, you ask about this, not the real problem. There's no need for a JobConfiguration class in HangFire. And talking about model suggests you're trying to use the wrong patterns

@Orace JobExpression is the action we want to register in Hangfire job manager.

@PanagiotisKanavos yes, that's a good way to put problem X I guess, but with additional data. JobConfiguration is just for the sake of providing unified way of passing data, I'm not opposed to different solutions as long as they can be re-used in different projects as well (this is meant to be a shared package for registering Hangfire).

You're using a completely wrong abstractions. You're trying to impose a Job/worker+Configuration model when Hangfire Expressions include both the action and its parameters. The entire expression passed to Enqueue is serialized in the database. That means JobConfiguration won't work at all. If you know what jobs are included in your project, a far better option would be to create extension methods  (eg .AddAccountingJobs, .AddMaintenanceJobs) that add each module's job, in a similar way .NET's middleware works.

@PanagiotisKanavos I have a small amount of jobs but would like to .AddOrUpdate or .RemoveIfExists all of them based on a value in appsettings, so extensions suggestion is not cut out for my scenario. Thank you for providing a reasonable answer though :)

If you need more dynamic registration you could create different registration classes per project, marked with an interface, that will actually register that project's jobs. Essentially you'll automate the discovery of the AddAccountingJobs method. You can use Reflection to find those classes OR, if you use DI in your project, you could register them using a common IJobRegistration interface and retrieve all of them with GetServices<IJobRegistration>

@SuperMenthol is not cut out for my scenario quite the opposite. Remember, .NET itself already works like this. You can control whether you call AddAccountingJobs with an if or you can pass an IConfiguration as a parameter to it and check the setting values. Those settings come from the config sources registered for Host configuration, and already include the appsettings file

@SuperMenthol so the real question is conditional setup, not dynamic configuration at all? That sounds like Feature Flags/Toggles. There's a built-in Feature management middleware that may help
